# How to get C input that accepts a float or a character as a value

Tags: c, input, char, calculator

As i said, i need to be able to accept the characters a b c d e as an input but it also needs to be able to accept any floating point numbers. i’m not sure if this is even possible but if someone knows a easy fix to this it would be really appreciated. I don’t want to use any inputs to ask the user what data type they will enter before hand.

Comment: Scan the input as string, parse the string. `strtod` is likely handy.

Comment: Read the string with `fgets()` and compare it with the valid options ("a", "b", "c", ...). If that fails, attempt to parse it as a double with `strtod()`. If that fails, print an error message and exit the program.

Comment: Or simply attempt to parse it as a `double`, and if that fails, treat it as a character.

Comment: What are the characters a b c d e ? Are this variables? A string with the characters `"abcde"`, a input file with this characters written into it? What do you mean with input? Do you get the input from files, form IOs (in case you use a microcontroller), via a socket, via Serial interface, via TCP, via GUI, ... ?

Answer (score 1):

The easy approach is to read a *line* of user input with `fgets()` into a *string* and then parse the string multiple ways.

Use `" %n"` to record the offset of the scan, if it got that far, to detect success and look for trailing junk.

Tolerate leading and trailing white-spaces.

```
// Read input as a,b,c,d,e or a float
// Return 2: if float
// Return 1: if char
// Return 0: neither
// Return EOF: end-of-file
int read_char_or_float(char *ch, float *f) {
  char buf[100];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    return EOF;
  }

  // Scan for white-space, one_a_to_e, white-space
  int n = 0;
  char s[2];
  sscanf(buf, " %1[a-e] %n", s, &n);
  if (n > 0 && buf[n] == '\0') {
    *ch = s[0];
    return 1;
  }

  // Scan for white-space, float, white-space
  n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, " %f %n", f, &n);
  if (n > 0 && buf[n] == '\0') {
    return 2;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Better code would use `strtof()` to parse the `float`, but something to get OP started.

```
  errno = 0;
  char *endptr;
  *f = strtof(buf, &endptr);  
  if (endptr > buf && errno == 0) {
    while (isspace(*((unsigned char*)endptr))) {
      endptr++;
    }
    if (*endptr == '\0') {
      return 2;
    }
  }
  return 0;
```